# Chain Complexes definition

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to know if this two definitions are equivalent in some sense.

Consider $R$ a comutative ring with unity.

(i) A chain complex is a pair $(\{M_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}, \{d_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}})$ such that $M_n$ are $R$-modules and $d_n: M_n \rightarrow M_{n - 1}$ are $R$-morphisms and the condition $d_{n - 1} \circ d_n = 0$ is satisfied.

(ii) A chain complex is a pair $(M,d)$ where $M$ is a $Z$-graded $R$-module and $d: M \rightarrow M$ is an endomorphism of degree one such that $d^2 = 0$.

ok, i did this:

(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i) $M = \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} M_n$ for $M_n$ $R$-submodules of $M$. Consider the pair  $(\{M_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}, \{d_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}})$ where $d_n$ are the restriction of $d$ to $M_n$, such a pair will be a chain complex in the definition (i).

(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii) Consider the external direct sum $\bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}^{\cdot} M_n$ and the maps $D_n: M_n \rightarrow \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}^{\cdot} M_n$ defined by $D_n(m) = \{m_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ such that $m_{n - 1} = d_n(m)$ and $m_j = 0$ for $j \neq n - 1$. The universal propriety of external direct sum give a morphism $d: \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}^{\cdot} M_n \rightarrow \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}^{\cdot} M_n$ such that $f \circ i_n = D_n$ where $i_n: M_n \rightarrow \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}^{\cdot} M_n$ are the canonical inclusions.

At this point i'm confused, is $\bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}^{\cdot} M_n$ a $Z$-graded $R$-module?

I saw this two definition in diferent texts.

Comment: what is the definition of "$\mathbb{Z}$-graded $R$-module"? Usually graded modules are defined over graded rings. also I think you mean the degree of the map in (ii) is $(-1)$, not $1$.

Comment: Let $G$ a group. We say that $M$ is a $ $G$-graded R$-módule if exists a famíly $\{M_i\}_{i \in G}$ of $R$-submodules such that $M = \bigoplus\limits_{i \in G}M_i$ and $R_iM_j \subset M_{(i+j)}$ for all $i,j \in G$. Yes, sorry, degree -1.

Comment: $R_i?$ So you are assuming the ring $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded, $R = \oplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}R_i$. But then $M_i$'s are not $R$-submodules of $M$. These are $R_0$-submodules. Also in the case (i), $R$ need not be graded.